# Unity 3d Asset Hunter v1.3.3

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets

After building project in unity, when I am trying to use Asset Hunter, it shows red, not turned to yellow. What could the issue be?

[image]

I have Asset Hunter v1.3.3, I am using UNITY 5.2.1f1

Comment: better to ask from the developer

Comment: Thank you @IroshanVithanage

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says: **Load Build Required**

Just click on cmd+b and create build. It will automatically create Build log which is required by asset hunter plugin.

Just let me know if you need to know any further.